# View stops animation after navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, cabasicanimation

I create my custom loading indicator. So, I update my view like this

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CAShapeLayer *progressLayer;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL isAnimating;

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.progressLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));
    [self updatePath];
}

- (void)updatePath {
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds));
    CGFloat radius = MIN(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) / 2, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) / 2) - self.progressLayer.lineWidth / 2;
    CGFloat startAngle = 3 * M_PI_2;
    CGFloat endAngle = self.endAngle;
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center radius:radius   startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];
    self.progressLayer.path = path.CGPath;
}
```

Animation starts here

```
- (void)startAnimating {
    if (self.isAnimating)
    return;

    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
    animation.keyPath = @"transform.rotation";
    animation.duration = 1.0f;
    animation.fromValue = @(0.0f);
    animation.toValue = @(2 * M_PI);
    animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;

    [self.progressLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:kLLARingSpinnerAnimationKey];
    self.isAnimating = true;
}

- (void)stopAnimating {
    if (!self.isAnimating)
        return;

    [self.progressLayer removeAnimationForKey:kLLARingSpinnerAnimationKey];
    self.isAnimating = false;
}

- (CAShapeLayer *)progressLayer {
    if (!_progressLayer) {
        _progressLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        _progressLayer.strokeColor = self.tintColor.CGColor;
        _progressLayer.fillColor = nil;
        _progressLayer.lineWidth = 1.5f;
    }
    return _progressLayer;
}
```

I have a tab bar app, so the problem is when animation start, I click to another tab and then return to first view, my custom indicator doesn't animate. Also this bug(feature) appear in collection view cells if I add my indicator to cells.
I add my indicator by calling simple method addSubview:

```
[view addSubview:indicator];
[indicator startAnimating];
```

How can I prevent stop animating after navigation? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you move from one view to another in tabBar app then the scope of that view is release so objet is alive. Also the basic usage of indicator is to let user know that he/she has to wait till that service/operation is complete and also u should be disabling the tabBar select index till indicator is finished. Rest it all depends on ur app usage. Suggestion UI is imp part of app.

Comment: @walle84 but why UIActivityIndicatorView works fine and do not stop?

Comment: I didn't got this line "my custom indicator doesn't animate. ". So doesn't animate in what sense ?

Comment: For stop purpose I'm not seeing that you provided a stop method. Still for stop there is "stopAnimating" method. Also provide more code for more clarity.

Comment: @walle84 I mean it displays without animation. Look at post updates, I added more code.

Comment: try placing it on your [UIWindow keyWindow]

Comment: Could u provide whole .h and .m file of your custom indicator so that I could add and check it for issue if possible as I don't have mush time to create it wholly.

Comment: @walle84 you can get it here, check LLARingSpinnerView.h https://github.com/WeLikeDigital/LLARingSpinnerView there some easy methods

Comment: ok will look into it and let u know if got solution for your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go,

//I have used a BOOL viewChange to check if spinner was running or not while user tapped to different view in tabBar.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{  //On initial run the viewChange will be false and the condition in if won't run but as spinnerView start animating u could change the viewChange flag to true.

  //So when user will be back from second view then this flag would be true and it will start animating.

  //As your work is complete then just stop animating and remove from view.

  if(viewChange){
     [spinnerView stopAnimating];
     [spinnerView removeFromSuperview];
     spinnerView = nil;
     spinnerView = [[LLARingSpinnerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2, 40, 40)];

     [self.view addSubview:spinnerView];
     [spinnerView startAnimating];
  }
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

//This is called when user move from current view to another and at that point we user won't be seeing the spinnerView so remove it and release it only if it's animating.

  if(spinnerView.isAnimating){
    viewChange = YES;
    [spinnerView stopAnimating];
    [spinnerView removeFromSuperview];
    spinnerView = nil;
  }
  else{
    viewChange = NO;
 }
}

- (IBAction)stopBtn:(id)sender{        //Spinner is stop animating with tap on button and is removed from the view.
  if(spinnerView.isAnimating){
      [spinnerView stopAnimating];
      [spinnerView removeFromSuperview];
      spinnerView = nil;               //release the obj of spinnerView.
  }
}

- (IBAction)btnTap:(id)sender{         //Spinner is start animating with tap on button
  if(!spinnerView)
    spinnerView = [[LLARingSpinnerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2, 40, 40)];
  spinnerView.lineWidth = 1.5f;
  spinnerView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
  [self.view addSubview:spinnerView];

  [spinnerView startAnimating];
}
```

Hope this helps out and if any doubt do let me know. Also if possible u should avoid user to move to another view when spinnerView is running as it indicates that some sort of service or update is running and at that point user should move to another view till it's finish.

Comment: Looks great thanks! But, I have the doubt about collection view cells. If I add this spinner to cell, it also stops animating. The obvious solution is to call reloadData in ViewWillAppear. But I'm afraid this is not very efficient. What do you, @walle84 , think about it?

Comment: I don't agree on using spinner in cell's and allowing user to move to another view. So you need to re-think on ur UI part. Also still if u want to go like that then more detailed info about ur collectionView would give me a clear idea of ur usage then I will be able to give u solution/suggestion.

Comment: I use spinner in cells with imageView while images is loading from internet.

Comment: why don't u put spinner on whole collectionView rather then every cell and till the images are gathher/loading in ur images don't remove spinner. Also download all images in one go and not make different calls for each cell so that when user scroll down/up then u could show images from imageArray(containing all images that were downloaded).

Comment: thanks for replies. But I can't load all images at once. It is very big load on network (it can be thousands of photos), I load  by 100 ones. And it's ugly UI if I add spinner to whole collection view.

Comment: Could u share your UI over here so I could have a look at it. And ur right about the load thing so 100 is good.

Comment: it's like the instagram profile view. When you scroll down the photos, it's preload and spinner is appeared on each photo placeholder.

Comment: U could use this [link](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) which makes network call in background and let u do whatever you want to do in foreground also as network call is done then u could update the UI. Do check it out, will be useful in ur case.

Comment: I've already use it ;) I think you catch the idea I don't want to download all images links array at one moment. I will try reload data to fix the problem.

Comment: Could u share a screenshot of your colelctionView? For better understanding.

Comment: http://postimg.org/gallery/1ng9lkwa/ there collection view and plain view @walle84

Comment: U need to reload data when back to collectionView and in cellForItemAtIndexPath method u could check if the image was loaded or not. In not loaded condition again make service call and show the spinner. Also when u move away from collectionView then release all spinner but do store images which were loaded(so when back then u would have some of them for display)

Comment: don't forget to vote up and tick this post as right :)